# Why does my game keep going even when there is no more spaces to fill

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

So, to further explain my question, when I fill my whole board in tic tac toe with "X" and "O" and there is no winner, the game keeps on playing even when the spaces are filled. It just keeps saying enter a row and column still. It doesn't know when to stop. I'm not sure whats wrong with my code.

**Problems where I think it is:** I think my problem lies in my **checkWinner function** because my bool winner = false is suppose return my statement "Its a tie" if every space on my board is filled but it doesn't output that. It also may be my main function.

How do I fix this problem because I've been stuck trying to figure it out. So if anyone can help, I appreciate it. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int ROWS = 3; // For the number of rows.
const int COLS = 3; // For the number of columns.
void showBoard(char[][COLS], int); // Shows the board.
void playerChoice(char[][COLS], char); // shows the player choice.
bool checkWinner(char[][COLS], string&); // check the winner.
char board[ROWS][COLS] = { { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' } };

int main()
{

    char board[ROWS][COLS] = { { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' }, { '*', '*', '*' } }; // displays
    whats inside the board.string gwinner = " "; // holds the winner until there is a winner.
    bool winner;
    int counter = 1;

    showBoard(board, 3); // displays the board.

    playerChoice(board, 'X');
    showBoard(board, 3);

    while (counter) {

        playerChoice(board, 'O');
        showBoard(board, 3);

        if (winner = checkWinner(board, gwinner))
            break;

        playerChoice(board, 'X');
        showBoard(board, 3);

        if (winner = checkWinner(board, gwinner))
            break;
    }
    cout << gwinner;
}

void showBoard(char arr[][COLS], int SIZE) // Displays the board.

{
    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)

            cout << '|' << arr[row][col];

        cout << '|' << endl;
    }
}

void playerChoice(char arr[][COLS], char name) // what row and column the user wants.
{
    int row, columns; // for the user to enter the row and column.
    int occupied;

    do {
        cout << "What row would you like?\n";
        cout << "Row: ";
        cin >> row;

        while (row < 1 || row > 3) // input validation.
        {
            cout << "Error please pick a row between 1 and 3.\n";
            cout << "Row: ";
            cin >> row;
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << "What column would you like?\n";
        cout << "Column: ";
        cin >> columns;

        while (columns < 1 || columns > 3) // input validation.

        {
            cout << "Error,please pick a column between 1 and 3.\n";
            cout << "Column: ";
            cin >> columns;
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (arr[row - 1][columns - 1] == '*') // checks to see if * is empty

        {

            arr[row - 1][columns - 1] = name; // diplays either X or O
            occupied = 1;
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nThis space is occupied.\n";
            cout << "Please select again\n";
            occupied = 0;
        }

    } while (occupied == 0);
}

bool checkWinner(char arr[][COLS], string& gwinner) // Check if the winner met the right conditions
{
    bool winner = false;
    if ((arr[0][0] == arr[0][1]) && (arr[0][1] == arr[0][2]) && (arr[0][1] != '*')) // checks row
    {
        winner = true;
        cout << "The winner is:" << arr[0][0] << endl;
    }

    else if ((arr[1][0] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[1][2]) && (arr[1][1] != '*')) // checks row
    {
        winner = true;
        cout << "The winner is:" << arr[1][0] << endl;
    }

    else if ((arr[2][0] == arr[2][1]) && (arr[2][1] == arr[2][2]) && (arr[2][1] != '*')) // checks row
    {
        winner = true;
        cout << "The winner is:" << arr[2][0] << endl;
    }

    else if ((arr[0][0] == arr[1][0]) && (arr[1][0] == arr[2][0]) && (arr[1][0] != '*')) // checks columns
    {
        winner = true;
        cout << "The winnner is:" << arr[0][0] << endl;
    }

    else if ((arr[0][1] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[2][1]) && (arr[1][1] != '*')) // checks
        columns
        {
            winner = true;
            cout << "The winnner is:" << arr[0][1] << endl;
        }

    else if ((arr[0][2] == arr[1][2]) && (arr[1][2] == arr[2][2]) && (arr[1][2] != '*')) // checks
        columns
        {
            winner = true;
            cout << "The winnner is:" << arr[0][2] << endl;
        }

    else if ((arr[0][0] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[2][2]) && (arr[1][1] != '*')) // checks
        diagonal

        {
            winner = true;
            cout << "The winnner is:" << arr[0][0] << endl;
        }

    else if ((arr[2][0] == arr[1][1]) && (arr[1][1] == arr[0][2]) && (arr[1][1] != '*')) // checks
        diagonal
        {
            winner = true;
            cout << "The winnner is:" << arr[2][0] << endl;
        }
    else {
        gwinner = "It's a Tie."; // else if the winner is a tie.
        winner = false;
    }
    return winner; // returns the winner
}
```

Comment: [Learn to use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763612/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Comment: Your check winner function doesn't distinguish between an incomplete game and a draw. It returns false in both cases.

Comment: There are two conditions that will exit your `while (counter) {` loop. (1) If `counter` becomes zero (but you initialize it to 1 and **never** change it inside the loop). (2) If `checkWinner` returns `true`. Why would you expect the loop to end if `checkWinner` returns `false`?.

Comment: @AdrianMole So how would I change it inside the loop? Would I set it equal to 0? I'm a little lost. For the `checkWinner` I thought a false would mean to return whatever I have in my {}. Btw I'm also beginning to learn to use c++, so some terms I don't understand.